# How we can do unit testing in windows form c# where i have built in private methods

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, unit-testing

```
private void name_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     char ch = e.KeyChar;
     if (!char.IsLetter (ch) && (ch != 8))
     {
         e.Handled = true;
     } 
}
```

1.**some part of the code.how to do unit testing for this code**

```
public int validation()
{
    int flag = 0;
    Regex Rx = new Regex(@"^[\p{L} \.'\-]{0,20}$");
    Regex Rx1 = new Regex(@"^[\p{L} \.'\-]{0,20}$");
    Regex Rx2 = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{10}$");
    if (name.Text=="")
    {
         name.Focus();
         errorProvider1.SetError(name, MessageBox.Show("enter your name", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
         flag = 1;
    }
    else if (fathername.Text == "")
    {
        fathername.Focus();
        errorProvider1.SetError(name, MessageBox.Show("Enter your father name", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

its a public method

Comment: Usually, only  the public interface of a class is unit-tested. For UI-related classes you of course also have the user interface aspect. This is handled either by putting the whole interaction logic in a separate class (e.g. the ViewModel class in the MVVM pattern), or by UI test frameworks like e.g. White.

Comment: can you fix the problem..please

Comment: Which problem exactly? Of course you can make the method internal or public and so somehow test it. But this will not test the real functionality implemented by this method, namely to restrict what can be entered in a text box (I assume). So please state first what exactly your unit test shall test.

Comment: check this out part of the program     public int validation()
            {
            int flag = 0;
            Regex Rx = new Regex(@"^[\p{L} \.'\-]{0,20}$");
            Regex Rx1 = new Regex(@"^[\p{L} \.'\-]{0,20}$");
            Regex Rx2 = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{10}$");
           
            
            if (name.Text=="")
            {
                name.Focus();
                errorProvider1.SetError(name, MessageBox.Show("enter your name", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
                flag = 1;
            }

Comment: If you want to add new information to your question, do this by editing the question. Information in comments is easily overlooked.

Comment: ok adding cheak out

Answer (score 1):

**Code Behind & Unit Tests:**

To answer your question, Ideally you should not test UI code behind files using unit test.   That would be taken care by the automated testing frameworks.

You should also use the frameworks like MVVM to keep the code behind files clean and that would help to increase overall maintainability and testability of the code.

**Non Code-Behind classes and Private methods**

Ideally you should not need to test private methods explicitly as they should be getting called through some public methods of the class.  Hence if all control flows of public methods is unit tested, then you don't need to write unit tests for private methods.

Below are couple of tips which may be useful for you.

**Tip 1: InternalsVisibleTo assembly attribute:**

Using this attribute internal methods / internal classes if you specify this attribute in your assembly.  UnitTestAssembly is the assembly where your unit tests are located.  The public key token is required only if strong naming of unit test assembly is done.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestAssembly, PublicKey=002400000...")]
```

**Tip 2: PrivateObject applicable only to MSTest framework:**

You can use private object to get private fields properties of an object.  You can refer documentation here.   This is applicable only if you are using MSTest unit testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

For testing vour `validation` method: One challenge is the `MessageBox.Show` call - you must get rid of this for unit tests.

**Option 1:**

Do not call `MessageBox.Show` directy but via an interface so that it can be mocked for unit tests.

```
public interface IMessageBoxService
{
    DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon);
}

class DefaultMessageBoxService : IMessageBoxService
{
    public DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(text, caption, buttons, icon);
    }
}

public class MyForm
{
    IMessageBoxService _messageBoxService; // use some IoC mechanism to set this

    public void validation()
    {
        if (...)
        {
            _messageBoxService.ShowMessageBox("enter your name", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Separate validation logic from UI. Unit-test only the validation logic.

```
public class MyForm
{
    // this method may also be in a different class
    public static bool ValidateName(string name, out string errorMessage)
    {
        errorMessage = null;
        if (name == "")
        {
            errorMessage = "enter your name";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int validation()
    {
        int flag = 0;
        string errorMessage;
        if (!ValidateName(name.Text, out errorMessage))
        {
            name.Focus();
            errorProvider1.SetError(name, MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error).ToString());
            flag = 1;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```